# Navigate to a new page without putting current page on back stack?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

In an Windows Phone 7 application I got a CurrentPage, which, on a special event does navigate to a new page using the NavigationService:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Now when the user clicks back on the NewPage I want the app to skip the CurrentPage and go directly to the MainPage of the app.

I tried to use NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry, but this removes the MainPage instead of the CurrentPage.

How do I navigate to a new page without putting the current on the back stack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When navigating to the NewPage.xaml pass along a parameter so you know when to remove the previous page from the backstack.

You can do this as such:

When navigating from **CurrentPage.xaml** to **NewPage.xaml** pass along **parameter**

```
    bool remove = true;
    String removeParam = remove ? bool.TrueString : bool.FalseString;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage.xaml?removePrevious="+removeParam , UriKind.Relative));
```

In the **OnNavigatedTo** event of **NewPage.xaml**, check whether to remove the previous page or not.

```
    bool remove = false;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("removePrevious"))
    {
        remove = ((string)NavigationContext.QueryString["removePrevious"]).Equals(bool.TrueString);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("removePrevious");
    }

    if(remove)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

This way, you can decide on the **CurrentPage.xaml** if you want to remove it from the backstack.

Comment: Now how do we do this on Windows Store apps? Seeing we don't seem to have `RemoveBackEntry()`?

Comment: I have not yet looked into that, all I know is that this works on WP7. If I happen to come across an answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you have called "NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()"?
I think you have to do it at the new page, not at the page you want to skip!

edit:
So to get a better picture: you are having mainpage -> 1rst sub Page (should be skipped at back navigation) -> 2nd sub page which is independed from 1rst sub page.

2 ideas:
1) Try to call "NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()" in the OnNavigatedFrom-Event of the 1rst sub page
2) Check in the OnNavigatedTo-Event of the 1rst sub page if the NavigationMode (see event args) == Back and navigate back once more.

Comment: I have to call it on the CurrentPage, since the NewPage does not know it needs to remove the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your calling RemoveBackEntry to early (While you're still on CurrentPage.xaml). Thats why its removing MainPage.xaml. When you navigate to NewPage.xaml, in the OnNavigatedTo event call NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry and that should fix the problem.

Comment: I have to call it on the CurrentPage, since the NewPage does not know it needs to remove the back stack.

Comment: @Sam Check out akalucas's answer. That's kind of what I had in mind with calling it in the OnNavigatedTo event. You'll also be able to tell whether or not your coming from CurrentPage.xaml or not.